# Clear / Empty Variable for next loop

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

I am having a situation in which I need to `clear` the variable `lastWord` so that `msgbox` show nothing in next `loop`.

Following code is just an Example.

```
Sub clear_lastWord_Variable()

    Dim wordArr() As String
    Dim lastword As String
    Do
        selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        selection.Find.Font.Bold = True
        With selection.Find
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
        End With
        selection.Find.Execute

        If selection.Find.Found Then

            wordArr = Split(selection, " ")

            For i = LBound(wordArr) To UBound(wordArr) Step 1
                lastword = wordArr(i)

            Next i

            MsgBox lastword

            ' here should be something to clear lastword
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't "clear" a non-object variable, you can only set it to a defined value. For a string variable, that's usually the empty string `""`.

```
lastword = ""
```

or (identical)

```
lastword = vbNullString
```

For object variables, there is `Set myObj = Nothing`.

Comment: Please look below, VARIANT type variable can be set to EMPTY and then checked by IsEmpty() function.

Comment: That is correct for `Variant`. The question was about `String` variables though. @MilanOparnica

Answer (score 8):

If your variable is not an object you can also do:

```
lastword = Empty
```